# Depth-first search that starts from the right side of the loop

Tags: matlab, find, sparse-matrix, depth-first-search, matlab-compiler

Currently, I have a function that list all the branch from level to level in the leftest side. I want to list all the branch in the rightest side but not sure how to list them.

My code is as follow:

```matlab
adj=SparseGraph;
next = cell(n,1);
for i = 1:n
    next{i} = find(adj(i,:));
end
```

Thank you for your time,

Original output is

```matlab
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
[9,10]
[9,10,11]
[10,11,12]
[11,12,13]
[12,13,14]
[13,14,15]
[14,15]
```

Desire output is

```matlab
[8,7,6,5,4,3,2]
[15,14]
[15,14,13]
[14,13,12]
[13,12,11]
[12,11,10]
[11,10,9]
[10,9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use MATLABs builtin `graph` class

```
G = graph(adj);
for k = 1:G.numnodes
    disp(G.dfsearch(k));
end
```